# Netbeans 7.0.1 can't read originally good file?

Tags: netbeans, encoding

I've been using NB for a long time, with different versions, but today something strange happened, I installed NB7.0.1 and tried to compile some old projects, but it couldn't open one file, saying :"The file cannot be safely opened with encoding GBK. Do you want to continue opening it ?" I pressed on "Yes" and it opened it with errors, lots of empty rectangles in places of the "." characters and some strange Chinese/Japanese characters, this file was a normal, good java file which I've worked on in Nb6.9, NB7.0, never caused any problem, now NB7.0.1 somehow can't open it, so I uninstalled NB7.0.1, and tried to open it with other editors like notepad,wordpad and NB6.9, now the all display strange characters. Seems NB7.0.1 changed it's encoding or the reading of it. Anyone has similar problem, and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue before.
when I closed and reopened the netbeans the Old project opened normally.